# Sort object array by two fields

Tags: c#, sorting, object

I'm making a simple deck class using a card class and trying to sort the card deck again after shuffling it.
Here's my code:

deck.OrderBy(a => a.Face).ThenBy(a => a.Suit); //not working

How would you attack the problem? Without making significant changes to the code.
I've tried using Linq OrderBy and ThenBy, but doesn't seem to work.

edit: tried this and it works deck = deck.OrderBy(a => Enum.Parse(typeof (Suit), a.Suit)).ThenBy(a => Enum.Parse(typeof (Face), a.Face)).ToArray(); since I am using enum for Face and Suit

Comment: _"doesn't seem to work well."_  - _How_ is it not working? What did you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: As far as I can see, it doesnt do anything

Comment: because the sorted list is returned. The sorting is not in place in the variable deck

Comment: OrderBy and ThenBy return collections and do not change the current collection.

Answer (score 2):

`OrderBy` and `ThenBy` do not change the existing collection, they only return the sorted collection, so you need to assign the return value of these methods to `deck`:

```
deck = deck.OrderBy(a => a.Face).ThenBy(a => a.Suit).ToArray();
```

You also need to use `ToArray`, otherwise you will not be able to assign the value to `deck` because of type mismatch.

Comment: @Yaner since the card face and suite are strings, use `deck.OrderBy(a => Enum.Parse(Deck.Face, a.Face).ThenBy(a => Enum.Parse(Deck.Suit, a.Suit).ToArray()`

Comment: Or even better, change the Face and Suit properties of Card to use the enums instead of strings.